# error: cannot find symbol in java/android phonegap/cordova plugin when importing jar

Tags: java, android, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework, id3

I want to modify ID3 tags (MP3 File) by using phonegap/cordova ionic. I found a library My ID3 Tags for android https://sites.google.com/site/eternalsandbox/myid3-for-android

but when I include jar file, it's shows the error while compiling ionic project.

```
C:\phonegap\coolplugin_app\platforms\android\src\CoolPlugin.java:45: er
             MusicMetadataSet src_set = null;
             ^
   symbol: class MusicMetadataSet
 C:\phonegap\coolplugin_app\platforms\android\src\CoolPlugin.java:47: er
                 src_set = new MyID3().read(src);
                               ^
   symbol: class MyID3
 C:\phonegap\coolplugin_app\platforms\android\src\CoolPlugin.java:48: er
             } catch (IOException e1) {
                      ^
   symbol: class IOException
 C:\phonegap\coolplugin_app\platforms\android\src\CoolPlugin.java:60: er
                     IMusicMetadata metadata = src_set.getSimplified();
```

how to solve this ? Am I missing some classes to inherit ? and where to include .jar file.

here is my plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    id="com.matd.coolplugin"
    version="0.2.11">
    <name>CoolPlugin</name>
    <description>The coolest Plugin ever implemented</description>
    <license>Apache 2.0</license>
    <keywords>cordova,coolest</keywords>
    <repo></repo>
    <issue></issue>
    <js-module src="www/CoolPlugin.js" name="CoolPlugin">
        <clobbers target="CoolPlugin" />
    </js-module>
    <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="CoolPlugin" >
                <param name="android-package" value="CoolPlugin"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/MyID3_for_Android.jar" target-dir="libs" />
        <source-file src="src/android/CoolPlugin.java" target-dir="src/" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hey, any news on this?  I am having the same problem

Comment: import all the missing reference on top of the java file

Comment: Try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941][1]. I explained different approaches for importing JAR files into Android studio. I hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941